# Hangfire client for multiple servers

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

I have a lot of .NET 5 and .NET 6 windows worker services and I am wondering if it would make sense to convert them all to Hangfire servers with a common Hangfire database (SQL Server) and then have just one Hangfire client with the UI to watch and manage them all.

All the jobs at this moment would be RecurringJobs and I am interested in the CRON flexibility that Hangfire provides.

My question really is:

1. Does this make sense?
2. How should the code in the Worker here look like:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
   while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
      await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
   }
}
```

Unfortunatly it looks like the Hangfire documentation is a bit outdated so this is not clear to me as I have not worked with Hangfire before.